# Getting the error "The Report Application Server Failed" - Crystal with VB.net

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports, report

Really weird thing is happening.  I have a form with two buttons.  One says view, one says print.  When I click on the view button the report views on the screen fine and then I can print with no problem, however when I click the print button to print directly to the printer, I receive the error "The Report Application Server Failed".

What is really weird is that it does not fail on all print jobs even though I could print the same document say, 3 times, it prints the first two and then fails on the third.

Any ideas?

This is in VS 2008

Answer (score 0):

```
crReportDocument.PrintToPrinter(1, False, 0, 0);
```

use this code its working with me !

Comment: Thanks I will give it a go and let you know how it worked out.

Comment: Ok I gave your piece of code and that did not work.  I am still getting the same error.  What is really weird is that it does not fail on all print jobs even though I could print the same document say, 3 times, it prints the first two and then fails on the third.

Answer (score -1):

The solution for that problem in my case was the space problem with my subreport using Cross tab report. I changed the field format property to Grow. I think this could work for you...